# How to edit the /etc/shadow file in the SD card from another computer?

Tags: permissions, password

I have a Raspberry Pi for which I forgot the password. I want to do [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98368/131225) to get access. So I removed the SD card and now have it in another machine (running Ubuntu). I can navigate to `/media/my_user_in_the_Ubuntu_machine/root/etc` and there I find the `shadow` file. However, it is protected and cannot even read it. Is there any solution to recover access to this Pi?

Comment: Edit the file as `root`?

Comment: How do you plan to create a cryptographic key to store in you /etc/shadow file?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81248/325016

Comment: `sudo whatever /media/my_user_in_the_Ubuntu_machine/root/etc/shadow` does not work. I guess that this would work if I am *sudoing* as one of the administrator users in the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of doing this by hand, so I took the code from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158400/etc-shadow-how-to-generate-6-s-encrypted-password#comment259421_158402 (thank you @cristian-ciupitu https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1174/cristian-ciupitu ) and I filled out the other necessary bits to manage the actual file.

```
mcra@yertle:~$ sudo bin/passwd-poke /media/mcra/rootfs/etc/shadow pi beammedownscottie
updated pi,
  was ['pi', '!$6$VbF8BUzOyvy3Fao1$vKu8ujm2sTgeWZQyyGGTFij8toc3RtUTkpNbfmSmJu4FlmrpSV.oL3dq1ugiIcEy3mk0bHZ5Fdt2cKhG2ytlz1', '18598', '0', '99999', '7', '', '', '\n']
  now ['pi', '$6$CXJ4W1ucar6HJVN9$IfE4ikt7UK6bQ0qX5MPlEL8qMoEwYXU4qf0Eda53TuHNnEFJZKJHRr5TjIQ1D4DehvfmbaoBt0.H3IC/BgwU4/', '19506', '0', '99999', '7', '', '', '\n']
mcra@yertle:~$ sudo ls -lrt /media/mcra/rootfs/etc/shad*
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow  964 May 13  2022 /media/mcra/rootfs/etc/shadow-
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1036 May 29 12:57 /media/mcra/rootfs/etc/shadow~
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1035 May 29 14:02 /media/mcra/rootfs/etc/shadow
```

Code is over at https://github.com/mcast/scripts/blob/master/bin/shadow-poke

Comment: If the issue is literally what it is in the question ("I have a Raspberry Pi for which I forgot the password"), it's probably easier to just delete the password:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168422/25985 ...Although that *does* require you be able to access `shadow` from another system if you cannot log in otherwise, note that this issue with it "being protected and I cannot even read it" is likely not reproducible: It is not possible to protect a file that way (ie., prevent it from being accessible if the storage is mounted elsewhere)...

Comment: ...All you can do is encrypt the fs or file (which doesn't apply here).  Ie., the real issue has to do with the Ubuntu system or how the card was mounted (the OS can prevent an unprivileged user from accessing something, but not root).  Note that using `sudo` depends upon the ubuntu user be an appropriately configured sudoer on the Ubuntu system, and that is not a normal default except on RpiOS.  Ie., it won't work just because the it does on the Pi unless you make it so.

Comment: (I don't have enough points to comment on the Q itself)

My interpretation of "cannot even read it" was just that the file is private to `root`. Using `sudo` on the host which mounts the SD will fix this - where it can be fixed, otherwise security is working as intended.