# Reboot and password issues

Tags: password, reboot

My son got a raspberry PiTop at a class at the Centre for Computimg History in Cambridge last week. We have had some issues rebooting since attempting to download recommended software. However, the Pi is now seeming to reboot following removal/ re-installation of the SD card and asking for a password to my son’s customised username (ie username@raspberrypi). The password he chose in the class is very memorable and we know we’ve typed it in correctly, but it is not accepted. In addition, when the Pi was set up, login was supposed to be automatic. A line comes up to the effect of -bash: password: command not found
I’m not sure what to do next.

Comment: we can't really tell what you have actually done.  I suggest you reimage the SD card and follow the instructions at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html

Comment: you may try to reset password using SD card in other computer: [raspbian - Forgot password for username pi - Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98353/forgot-password-for-username-pi)  or [How to reset forgotten password and/or retrieve forgotten username - Raspberry Pi Forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=319398)

Comment: *"password: command not found"* -> The command is `passwd`, no "or" in it.